# Silverlight binding - Apply Not or ! before binding to Checkbox.IsChecked property

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I use to bind a bool variable of a class to a IsChecked property of Checkbox. What i want to do is to bind 'NOT' of the original value, like IsChecked = Binding Not(IsSelected), please let me know how this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a Convertor. A convertor class implements IValueConverter and can convert the binding value into something else, in your case, negate it. You can do it like this:

```
public class BoolInverseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
            return !(bool)value;

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```